# Several Fields on a Single Row while using CBVs & Bootstrap

Tags: django, django-class-based-views, django-crispy-forms

I am working on a project using Bootstrap and making use of Class Based Views. The forms that are rendered automagically are quite nice. But I want to make one simple change. Given a model that has city, state & zip fields, I want the form to render all three off those fields on the same row.

```
Name [                                    ]
Addr [                                    ]
City [        ]  State [  ]   Zip [       ]  <-- 3 fields, 1 row
```

I assume this is a pretty common task that has an elegant solution, but I have not found it. I was hoping django-crispyforms Row('city', 'state', 'zip'), would do in the Layout but that did not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't used crispy forms in a while but I believe with bootstrap you have to do something like example below because you cannot simply insert form elements into a row:

```
Row(
  Div('city', css_class='span4'),
  Div('state', css_class='span4'),
  Div('zip', css_class='span4')
)
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked.  I had a small complication because I use a theme that adds a 300px height to the span class. I made a simple css for the page and added Div( ... css_class='row-fluid') to get the alignment I wanted.